# Using FormEditor, how can I programmatically give focus to the content instead of the header?

Tags: eclipse, forms, rcp

I am using a `FormEditor` to create a multipage form in my RCP application. When opening the form, the focus goes to the header. I want the focus to go onto my page content, not the header. How can I do this?

I tried overriding `setFocus()` on my `FormPage`, but I can't figure out the correct combination of getters to get to where I want to go. This is what I have so far, but it's still giving focus to the header:

```
@Override
public void setFocus() {
    getManagedForm().getForm().getContent().setFocus();
}
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Are you using parts on the page (something like `SectionPart`)? The focus should be set automatically to the first part.

Comment: I am creating a header. So yes, the focus is automatically set to the first part, but that is not the part that I want. I'm not using a section part though - just a composite with a label and a tree viewer in it.